# instagram-ruby-gem - What happens when rate limit is exceeded?

Tags: ruby, instagram

I am using the Instagram ruby gem. What would happen if my application were to go over the rate limit? Would there be some exception, and if there will, then what?

Comment: See https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/blob/master/lib/instagram/error.rb

Comment: You'll get a rate limit exception, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, could you post it a an answer so I can accept it?